# Autofac independent scope when resolving IEnumerable<Service>

Tags: autofac

I have a collection of services which are resolved like this:

```
//other scope, such as default per http request in aspnet core

// new scope is created which is not part of web request scope
using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
   var services = scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<MyService>>();
}
```

However the problem is that, the scope is shared between all of Enumerable items, how to resolve them so that each of them get a fresh scope?

Answer (score 0):

There are two pieces to do this. You need to register your dependency as instance per lifetime scope, and then you need to create a nested scope and resolve your dependency with it.

```
public class MyModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<MyService1>(ThisAssembly)
            .As<MyService>
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<MyService2>(ThisAssembly)
            .As<MyService>
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<MyService3>(ThisAssembly)
            .As<MyService>
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    }
}
```

then you should be able to correctly resolve new instances in nested scopes like so:

```
using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
   var services = scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<MyService>>();
}
```

Comment: @SHM can i see the code where you register the dependency?

Comment: Thanks Mike, however the problem is that each IEnimerable item should be resolved in a separate scope.

Comment: i have to wonder why such a thing is necessary. it sounds like you should be registering the services with `.InstancePerDependency()`?

Comment: No, Some of my services are not thread safe, so i need to get one instance per thread and execute operations on them in parallel.